# Bootstrap mobile nav not showing when using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've added angular to my bootstrap project and I've noticed that the mobile nav button doesn't collapse the menu any more.  This was previously working.

[This is the page where I have this issue](http://hoteldemo.freevar.com/jobboard/#)

```
<!-- TOP NAV -->
<div class="container-100-percent"> 
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-header"> 
    <button aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button> 
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Top Tech Jobs</a> 
</div> 
<nav class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> 
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JOBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CANDIDATES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLIENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul> 
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><button type="button" class="btn-register"><a href="#">Register</a></button></li>
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; or</li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm not sure what the best way to fix this is.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the mobile navigator needs the javascript bootstrap file. try to put the bootstrap...js after the jquery.js

Comment: Unbelievable!  That worked thank you, think I've stayed up too late.  If you write that as your answer I'll accept it.